# Free Transform Rectangle on JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am new to the JavaScript canvas element.  I actually just started a few hours ago.  I'm working on a free transform of a rectangular section of an image.  (For an example of what I am calling a "free transform," see this:  http://www.html5.jp/test/perspective_canvas/demo1_en.html.  Please note that I do not want to be able to allow the user to transform the image with handles as this example features.)

I know a little bit of how to transform a large image, but I want to transform only the left half (for example) of an image.  How can I single out a section and free transform it?  I'm guessing I should start by loading the image.  I'm also betting the solution will involve marking the left side with paths.  But setTransform() doesn't given me the control I need.  I would like to have a function similar to this:

```
function freeTransform(canvas, image,
  startX1, startY1, startX2, startY2, startX3, startY3, startX4, startY4,
  endX1, endY1, endX2, endY2, endX3, endY3, endX4, endY4)
```

But the canvas's context does not have this function (as far as I know).  Would someone give me some direction?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

The html canvas cannot transform 1 corner of a rectangle using its common 2d context.

You can use "triangulation" to deform an image in canvas 2d to give it perspective:

http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/canvas/perspective.html

You can get closer to a perspective transform using canvas's 3d context (webGL).

You can use non-parallel transforms to deform an image in webGL to give it perspective:

http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-perspective/

Comment: Your answer eventually set me on the right path.  It's a little late, but I want to say thank you and mark yours as the answer.